# Docker: there is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: docker

I am trying to launch a docker container ; the container exits with status code 1, indicating an error. It looks like a memory error ; however, the requested memory (~900Mo) is lower than the available memory (~8Go). `docker logs` yields the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000ca660000, 899284992, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 899284992 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# logs/hs_err_pid1.log
```

My `docker info` is as such:

```
Containers: 5
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 32
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
 Windows:
 LCOW:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 17134 (17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.829)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 7.813GiB
Name: DESKTOP-OB3P5AU
ID: AYR7:F43F:MI7W:4JSM:EA5V:VXNB:T3HP:ZTL2:AZ2F:KFCM:463Q:RXJG
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2019-06-24T22:41:43.3487574+02:00
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Do you know how I can solve this?

For info, my `Dockerfile` is as such, and there was no problem when building the image.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN adduser -D microblog

WORKDIR /home/microblog

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev libffi-dev
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn 'pymysql<0.9'

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY microblog.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP microblog.py

RUN chown -R microblog:microblog ./
USER microblog

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

Comment: From `OSType: windows`, you use windows container, but `python:3.6-alpine` is linux image, and, your dockerfile just related to python, but you get jvm log... Doubt how you get above, maybe restart your machine check again.

Comment: @atline thank you for noticing this. What would bea good alternative on Windows? I tried `FROM python:3.6-oryx` but it doesn't seem to be the right syntax... As for the jvm log, there is some client-side JS in my flask app via `Flask-bootstrap`, could that be an explanation?

Comment: When we said `OSType: windows`, it means it's `windows container on windows10`, when we said `OSType: linux`, it means it's linux container on windows10`. So you insist to use windows container? But your ENTRYPOINT is `./boot.sh`, it should use linux container. In fact, what I mean is: I'm lost how you can manage the above log with linux image on windows container of windows10, I think you should get log with linux image on linux container of windows10... Sorry, I'm lost by your question, wait other man's comments...

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when running the docker on AWS. But you can solve this by increasing the memory available for java to run the application by passing the parameter below to the docker:
-e ES_JAVA_OPTS = "- Xms108m -Xmx108m"

Hope this helps! Vlw!